# jQuery and wcf service and windows services

Tags: c#, jquery, service

IWam created a c# WCF Service Application project in vs2012. Ican test my service on vs2012.But I will adding my project to windows services. So I can connaction form my jquery client program. my jquery code is

```
$.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    url:"http://localhost:50992/Service1.svc?singleWsdl",
    processData:false,
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function(xhr,status,error){
        alert(error);
    }
})
```

the url is my wcf project url.But when I closing my wcf test panel the service is stopping.Iwill add my wxf project to my windows services.So I can connect to this service from jquery.What can I do to adding my wcf service to windows services ?

Comment: is there a question in there?

Comment: the quastion : what can I do to adding my wcf service to windows services ?

Answer (score 0):

use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/132809/Calling-WCF-Services-using-jQuery) article and [this](http://blog.thomaslebrun.net/2011/11/jquery-calling-a-wcf-service-from-jquery/#.UQ5mkaVwrgM)

```
function GetTeamData(teamId, weekNumber) {
    $.ajax(
    {
        async: true,
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "../../Services/RunningBarbusService.svc/GetTeamData",
        dataType: "json",
        data: '{"teamId":"' + teamId + '", "weekNumber":"' + weekNumber + '"}',
        success: function (content) {
            DisplayRun(map, content);
        }
    });
}
```